# Cannot get Atheros AR9285 to work on 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, atheros, ath9k

I've already went through all possible advices and still cannot start my Atheros AR9285 wireless card.

I have a laptop Toshiba Portege Z830 where the WiFi already worked under Windows 7.
But after migration on Ubuntu 12.10. I'm not able get it work.

This is what I see on command `lshw`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0500000-c050ffff
```

This is what I see on command `rfkill list`

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a Toshiba NB305 netbook here, with the same Atheros wireless chipset.  The "hard block" claims that a hardware switch has been used to disable the wireless, but there is no hardware switch to do this! (Ubuntu 12.04LTS, and no matter what kernel I try it says the same thing)

Comment: I'd be surprised if you get anything to work on 12.10. It's been unsupported since May of 2014: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

to enable the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with

```
lsmod |grep mac80211
```

which gives you the driver name currently working with your wireless device. *AR9285* should be using **ath9k** by default. But in your case it seems your wireless adapter is not enabled at all. You can try this way

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

It's reported the above workaround solves the wireless connection problem on certain Atheros AR928x platform.